# I removed nvidia driver and lshw -c video still shows nvidia

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gui

Today I tried to activate the newer experimental drivers and both 304 and 310 failed to even install. So I tried the regular nvidia driver 295.40 for the 20th time today (I had lag issues and was testing Nouveau vs Nvidia with dual monitor and Unity2D-3D)

Within my tty1 I tried to remove nvidia:

`sudo apt-get remove nvidia-settings nvidia-current and purge too`

reboot, nothing.
So when `lshw -c video` displayed nvidia as my driver I tried

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` since I read ubuntu would "reset" the GUI conf but

reboot, nothing.

So next I tried `sudo jockey-text --disable=xorg:nvidia_current`
And nothing has worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since then I've tried to play with `jockey-text` and I found out that `jockey-text -l` displayed that `xorg:nvidia_current_updates` was in use even though I couldn't install it in the 1st place.

So I disabled it but then `xorg:nvidia_experimental_304` was in use and when I repeated the former process it showed that `experimental_310` too was in use.

So all of the 4 drivers were in use "simultaneously" which was not ok obviously.
Now that there is only one working, I have a GUI again.

I posted this because it's scary that you lose your GUI so easily, that kind of bug is way to easy to make happen since the additional drivers panel showed that NONE were in use...